# pattern matching in perl including files which have signs in their names

Tags: perl

Supposed to have an array and I want to find corresponding file in the current directory. I have a problem with pattern matching with those file which have a sign in their names but for the rest everything is OK!

```
files:
========
A+B-C_www.txt
A-B_CC.books.#1.txt

#!/usr/perl/bin

my @a = qw(A+B-C_www A-B_CC.books.#1);

my $dir = ".";
opendir(DIR, $dir);
my @files = grep(/txt$/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@files){
    for (my $i=0, $i<=$#a, $i++)
      if ($file =~ m/$a[$i]){
        do some stuff ....}
      else{
        do some stuff .... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because regular expressions have special characters with special meanings.

You can fix this with the `\Q` and `\E` regex modifiers.

```
if ($file =~ m/\Q$a[$i]\E/ ) {
```

Also - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. I assume that the broken regex in your original code (no trailing `/`) is a typo.

I'd also suggest instead of `readdir` and `grep` you could do both with:

```
while ( my $file = glob ( "*.txt" ) ) {
```

Also: Your pattern match is a substring match. You may need text anchors if that's not what you intend.

Comment: It may be better to use glob here, since that notation is finnicky,

Comment: Well, `$dir` was hardcoded as `.`. I believe in that scenario `glob ( "*.txt" )` won't have a problem?

Comment: No, that's fine. just answering my question. This will self-destruct.

Answer (score 2):

Irrelevant of the pattern matching issues that have already been addressed by the above answers, you could write you code more idiomatically with a grep statement instead of an inner for loop:

```
while ( my $file = glob('*.txt') ) {
   my $has_match = grep { $file =~ m|\Q$_\E| } @a; 

   if ( $has_match ) {
      # do something 
   } 
   else {
      # do something
   }
}
```

Comment: meh, I'd use `my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @a; my $re = qr/^(?:$pat)\z/;` ... `if ($file =~ $re)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to escape your pattern before interpolation.

```
my $pattern = quotemeta($a[$i]);
if ($file =~ m/$pattern/) {
}
```

Comment: if ($file =~ quotemeta($a[$i])){ }
works perfectly! is it correct?

Comment: @EpiMan, Yes, If the RHS of `=~` isn't a m//, tr/// or s/// operator, an m// is implied, using the result of the expression as the pattern.